# Can I use JQuery mobile with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, jquery-mobile

I would like to build a mobile web app and I am a bit curious of what technology I can use.I am thing of writing the server side in Nodejs but I am not sure if I can combine it with Jquery mobile?

Comment: Yes, you can. jQuery Mobile is `basically` a jQuery UI for mobile devices. It works together with any backend tech.

Comment: remember that nodeJS is good for real time and loads of concurrent connections, if you dont need that than wait a bit since nodeJS is still heavily under development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because front and back end should be totally modularized it shouldn't matter what your backend is to be able to use jQuery Mobile. And it shouldn't matter what your frontend is to use NodeJS. So the answer is yes.